# Android notifications scheduling with background_fetch package failing in Flutter app: what's causing it and how can I fix it?

Tags: android, flutter

I'm developing a Flutter App (at this point I'm only worrying about Android support), and one of the main parts of the app is that it automatically figures out when a particular event happens during the week and schedules a notification to show at that time.

After running into significant reliability issues with Android Alarm Manager, a number of people recommended that I use the `background_fetch` package with the `scheduleTask` method instead.

To test it, I'm calling the method manually with a button and setting a delay of 15 seconds. This way I can see if it's firing properly or not.

```
import 'package:background_fetch/background_fetch.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

import 'notification.dart';

const firstTaskId =
    'com.example.project-name-first';
const secondTaskId = 'com.example.project-name-second';

Future<void> initializeBackgroundFetch() async {
  await BackgroundFetch.configure(
    BackgroundFetchConfig(
      minimumFetchInterval: 15,
      stopOnTerminate: false,
      enableHeadless: true,
      requiresBatteryNotLow: false,
      requiresCharging: false,
      requiresStorageNotLow: false,
      requiresDeviceIdle: false,
      requiredNetworkType: NetworkType.NONE,
    ),
    _onTask,
    _onTaskTimeout,
  );

  BackgroundFetch.registerHeadlessTask(
      NotificationService.firstNotification);
  BackgroundFetch.registerHeadlessTask(
      NotificationService.secondNotification);
}

Future<void> _onTask(String taskId) async {
  if (kDebugMode) {
    print(
        '[BackgroundFetch | initializeBackgroundFetch] Event `$taskId` received.');
  }
  try {
    switch (taskId) {
      case firstTaskId:
        NotificationService.firstNotification();
        break;
      case secondTaskId:
        NotificationService.secondNotification();
        break;
    }
  } finally {
    BackgroundFetch.finish(taskId);
  }
}

Future<void> _onTaskTimeout(String taskId) async {
  if (kDebugMode) {
    print(
        '[BackgroundFetch | initializeBackgroundFetch] Task `$taskId` has timed out.');
  }
}

void scheduleTask(String taskId) {
  BackgroundFetch.scheduleTask(TaskConfig(
    taskId: taskId,
    delay: const Duration(seconds: 15).inMilliseconds,
    periodic: false,
    forceAlarmManager: false,
    stopOnTerminate: false,
    enableHeadless: true,
  ));
}
```

`initializeBackgroundFetch` is being called in `main`.

Here's what happens:

- Waiting with the app open: works
- Waiting with the app minimized: works
- Waiting with the app closed ("swiping it up"): doesn't work

In the last case, it just never fires. Once every 20 times trying it or so it'll work, but not reliably in the slightest.